# How to pronounce Abbott?

Tags: pronunciation

> ABC presenter's pronunciation for his Prime Minister -> [Abbott](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/428) ;
>   [original programme](http://www.abc.net.au/news/abcnews24/programs/the-drum/)

The presenter, as do other Aussies in the programme, pronounces **Abbott** as /ˈɛb ət/, while [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abbott?s=t) has /ˈæb ət/. Is the dictionary wrong?

When they in Australia call their Prime Minister /ˈɛb ət/, others do /ˈæb ət/?

Or /æ/, dragged by /b/, has approached to /ɛ/?

(When people say /ɛ/ instead of /æ/ it's called broad accent in wikipedia.org, I don't believe they are using it.)

Comment: It's just that Aussies often pronounce /æ/ (as in "cat") as /ɛ/ (as in "bed"). So do South Africans, and probably many other "dialectal" speakers. These are *not significant differences* to most Anglophones - we quickly get used to people with different accents consistently applying such vowel changes.

Comment: Everything gets shorter: *bed* is close to /bɪd/. Some [IPA helper charts](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm) don't cover AuE at all.

Comment: And names vary with region and family history. Hence while the composer Dvořák is /ˈdvɔr̝ɑːk/ his relative who designed the keyboard is /ˈdvɔræk/.

Comment: The proper pronunciation is "HEEEEEYYYYY ABBBOTTTTTT!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pronunciation differs between dialects. Dictionary.com's pronunciation is most likely a General American dialect where "Abbott" would indeed be pronounced as in their example.

With regards to names, pronunciation is dictated by parents for given names and culture/tradition for surnames. If Australians typically pronounce Abbott as /ˈɛb ət/ then it would follow that their Prime Minister's name should be pronounced /ˈɛb ət/. In the end, the final authority would be Abbott himself.